What is the error in the code? Why I am getting internal error while solving it in cplex opl
int nm=4;
int r=5;
range num=1..nm;
range hr=1..r;
int scale=100;
float m[hr]=[1026.8,1061.65,1096.5,1068.35, 1040.2];
float n[hr]=[736,713,690,667,644];
// Declaration of Decision variables
dvar float+ e[num][hr];
dvar float+ f[num][hr];
dvar float c[hr];
dvar float d[hr];
using CP;
  dexpr float b[i in hr]=(((m[i]+c[i]-d[i])^2)+n[i]^2);
  dexpr float nb[i in hr]=sqrt(b[i]);
  dexpr float amax=max(i in hr)(b[i]);
  dexpr float nf=1/sum(i in hr)nb[i];
            
// Objective
minimize  amax*nf;
subject to {
 forall(i in hr){
   c[i]==sum(k in num)e[k][i];
   d[i]==sum(k in num)f[k][i];
 } 
 forall (i in num){
   forall(j in hr){
     0<=e[i][j]<=1;
     0<=f[i][j]<=1;
     e[i][j]+f[i][j]<=2;
   }
 }
}

If I am writing the constraint as e[i][j]+f[i][j]==2, then I am getting the solution, However, the inequality constraint (e[i][j]+f[i][j]<=2) leads to internal error.

The following model works fine:
using CP;

int nm=4;
int r=5;
range num=1..nm;
range hr=1..r;
int scale=100;
float m[hr]=[1026.8,1061.65,1096.5,1068.35, 1040.2];
float n[hr]=[736,713,690,667,644];
// Declaration of Decision variables

dvar int+ scalee[num][hr];
dvar int+ scalef[num][hr];
dvar int scalec[hr];
dvar int scaled[hr];


dexpr float e[i in num][j in hr]=scalee[i][j]/scale;;
dexpr float f[i in num][j in hr]=scalef[i][j]/scale;
dexpr float c[i in hr]=scalec[i]/scale;
dexpr float d[i in hr]=scaled[i]/scale;

  dexpr float b[i in hr]=(((m[i]+c[i]-d[i])^2)+n[i]^2);
  dexpr float nb[i in hr]=sqrt(b[i]);
  dexpr float amax=max(i in hr)(b[i]);
  dexpr float nf=1/sum(i in hr)nb[i];
            
// Objective
minimize  amax*nf;
subject to {
 forall(i in hr){
   c[i]==sum(k in num)e[k][i];
   d[i]==sum(k in num)f[k][i];
 } 
 forall (i in num){
   forall(j in hr){
     0<=e[i][j]<=1;
     0<=f[i][j]<=1;
     e[i][j]+f[i][j]<=2;
   }
 }
}

